# сумма client элементов ассоциативного массива JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Есть вот такой код

```js
var daCityNum = 77;
var daCities = [{
"num": "1",
"name": ["Республика Адыгея", "Республики Адыгея"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "44.608865",
    "long": "40.098548"
},
"clients": "454"
}, {
"num": "2",
"name": ["Республика Башкортостан", "Республики Башкортостан"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "54.735147",
    "long": "55.958727"
},
"clients": "7936"
}, {
"num": "3",
"name": ["Республика Бурятия", "Республики Бурятия"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "51.834464",
    "long": "107.584574"
},
"clients": "607"
}, {
"num": "4",
"name": ["Республика Алтай", "Республики Алтай"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "51.958182",
    "long": "85.960373"
},
"clients": "773"
}, {
"num": "5",
"name": ["Республика Дагестан", "Республики Дагестан"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "42.98306",
    "long": "47.504682"
},
"clients": "279"
}, {
"num": "6",
"name": ["Республика Ингушетия", "Республики Ингушетия"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "43.16678",
    "long": "44.803574"
},
"clients": "61"
}, {
"num": "7",
"name": ["Кабардино-Балкария", "Кабардино-Балкарии"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "43.485259",
    "long": "43.607072"
},
"clients": "612"
}, {
"num": "8",
"name": ["Республика Калмыкия", "Республики Калмыкия"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "46.307743",
    "long": "44.269759"
},
"clients": "763"
}, {
"num": "9",
"name": ["Карачаево-Черкессия", "Карачаево-Черкессии"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "44.228374",
    "long": "42.04827"
},
"clients": "130"
}, {
"num": "10",
"name": ["Республика Карелия", "Республики Карелия"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "61.785017",
    "long": "34.346878"
},
"clients": "1149"
}, {
"num": "11",
"name": ["Республика Коми", "Республики Коми"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "61.668793",
    "long": "50.836399"
},
"clients": "847"
}, {
"num": "12",
"name": ["Республика Марий Эл", "Республики Марий Эл"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "56.631595",
    "long": "47.886178"
},
"clients": "545"
}, {
"num": "13",
"name": ["Республика Мордовия", "Республики Мордовия"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "54.187433",
    "long": "45.183938"
},
"clients": "1293"
}, {
"num": "14",
"name": ["Республика Саха (Якутия)", "Республики Саха (Якутия)"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "62.027216",
    "long": "129.732178"
},
"clients": "701"
}, {
"num": "15",
"name": ["Республика Алания", "Республики Алания"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "43.02115",
    "long": "44.68196"
},
"clients": "494"
}, {
"num": "16",
"name": ["Республика Татарстан", "Республики Татарстан"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "55.796289",
    "long": "49.108795"
},
"clients": "4445"
}, {
"num": "17",
"name": ["Республика Тыва", "Республики Тыва"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "51.719086",
    "long": "94.437757"
},
"clients": "175"
}, {
"num": "18",
"name": ["Удмуртская Республика", "Удмуртской Республики"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "56.852676",
    "long": "53.206891"
},
"clients": "1713"
}, {
"num": "19",
"name": ["Республика Хакасия", "Республики Хакасия"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "53.721152",
    "long": "91.442387"
},
"clients": "376"
}, {
"num": "21",
"name": ["Чувашская Республика", "Чувашской Республики"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "56.146277",
    "long": "47.251079"
},
"clients": "1714"
}, {
"num": "22",
"name": ["Алтайский край", "Алтайского края"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "53.346785",
    "long": "83.776856"
},
"clients": "1949"
}, {
"num": "23",
"name": ["Краснодарский край", "Краснодарского края"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "45.03547",
    "long": "38.975313"
},
"clients": "4794"
}, {
"num": "24",
"name": ["Красноярский край", "Красноярского края"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "56.010563",
    "long": "92.852572"
},
"clients": "7336"
}, {
"num": "25",
"name": ["Приморский край", "Приморского края"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "43.115536",
    "long": "131.885485"
},
"clients": "2362"
}, {
"num": "26",
"name": ["Ставропольский край", "Ставропольского края"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "45.04333",
    "long": "41.969101"
},
"clients": "2614"
}, {
"num": "27",
"name": ["Хабаровский край", "Хабаровского края"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "48.480223",
    "long": "135.071917"
},
"clients": "2536"
}, {
"num": "28",
"name": ["Амурская область", "Амурской области"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "50.29064",
    "long": "127.527173"
},
"clients": "830"
}, {
"num": "29",
"name": ["Архангельская область", "Архангельской области"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "64.539911",
    "long": "40.515753"
},
"clients": "2003"
}, {
"num": "30",
"name": ["Астраханская область", "Астраханской области"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "46.347869",
    "long": "48.033574"
},
"clients": "814"
}, {
"num": "31",
"name": ["Белгородская область", "Белгородской области"],
"popular": "true",
"coord": {
    "lat": "50.59566",
    "long": "36.587223"
},
"clients": "2821"
}, {
"num": "32",
"name": ["Брянская область", "Брянской области"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "53.243562",
    "long": "34.363407"
},
"clients": "1367"
}, {
"num": "33",
"name": ["Владимирская область", "Владимирской области"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "56.129057",
    "long": "40.406635"
},
"clients": "1317"
}, {
"num": "34",
"name": ["Волгоградская область", "Волгоградской области"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "48.707067",
    "long": "44.516948"
},
"clients": "5237"
}, {
"num": "35",
"name": ["Вологодская область", "Вологодской области"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "59.220496",
    "long": "39.891523"
},
"clients": "3841"
}, {
"num": "36",
"name": ["Воронежская область", "Воронежской области"],
"popular": "true",
"coord": {
    "lat": "51.660781",
    "long": "39.200269"
},
"clients": "1851"
}, {
"num": "37",
"name": ["Ивановская область", "Ивановской области"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "57.000348",
    "long": "40.973921"
},
"clients": "1404"
}, {
"num": "38",
"name": ["Иркутская область", "Иркутской области"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "52.287054",
    "long": "104.281047"
},
"clients": "2970"
}, {
"num": "39",
"name": ["Калининградская область", "Калининградской области"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "54.710454",
    "long": "20.512733"
},
"clients": "1796"
}, {
"num": "40",
"name": ["Калужская область", "Калужской области"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "54.513845",
    "long": "36.261215"
},
"clients": "1485"
}, {
"num": "41",
"name": ["Камчатский край", "Камчатского края"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "53.024075",
    "long": "158.643566"
},
"clients": "252"
}, {
"num": "42",
"name": ["Кемеровская область", "Кемеровской области"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "55.354727",
    "long": "86.088374"
},
"clients": "2426"
}, {
"num": "43",
"name": ["Кировская область", "Кировской области"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "58.603591",
    "long": "49.668014"
},
"clients": "1094"
}, {
"num": "44",
"name": ["Костромская область", "Костромской области"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "57.767961",
    "long": "40.926858"
},
"clients": "553"
}, {
"num": "45",
"name": ["Курганская область", "Курганской области"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "55.441004",
    "long": "65.341118"
},
"clients": "895"
}, {
"num": "46",
"name": ["Курская область", "Курской области"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "51.73083",
    "long": "36.193186"
},
"clients": "1438"
}, {
"num": "47",
"name": ["Ленинградская область", "Ленинградской области"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "",
    "long": ""
},
"clients": ""
}, {
"num": "48",
"name": ["Липецкая область", "Липецкой области"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "52.60882",
    "long": "39.59922"
},
"clients": "1205"
}, {
"num": "49",
"name": ["Магаданская область", "Магаданской области"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "59.565151",
    "long": "150.808586"
},
"clients": "98"
}, {
"num": "50",
"name": ["Московская область", "Московской области"],
"popular": "true",
"coord": {
    "lat": "55.815792",
    "long": "37.380031"
},
"clients": "11039"
}, {
"num": "51",
"name": ["Мурманская область", "Мурманской области"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "68.970682",
    "long": "33.074981"
},
"clients": "666"
}, {
"num": "52",
"name": ["Нижегородская область", "Нижегородской области"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "56.326797",
    "long": "44.006516"
},
"clients": "3976"
}, {
"num": "53",
"name": ["Новгородская область", "Новгородской области"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "58.52281",
    "long": "31.269915"
},
"clients": "517"
}, {
"num": "54",
"name": ["Новосибирская область", "Новосибирской области"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "55.030199",
    "long": "82.92043"
},
"clients": "5075"
}, {
"num": "55",
"name": ["Омская область", "Омской области"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "54.989342",
    "long": "73.368212"
},
"clients": "3809"
}, {
"num": "56",
"name": ["Оренбургская область", "Оренбургской области"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "51.768199",
    "long": "55.096955"
},
"clients": "2397"
}, {
"num": "57",
"name": ["Орловская область", "Орловской области"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "52.970371",
    "long": "36.063837"
},
"clients": "699"
}, {
"num": "58",
"name": ["Пензенская область", "Пензенской области"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "53.195042",
    "long": "45.018316"
},
"clients": "3360"
}, {
"num": "59",
"name": ["Пермский край", "Пермской области"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "58.01045",
    "long": "56.229434"
},
"clients": "3095"
}, {
"num": "60",
"name": ["Псковская область", "Псковской области"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "57.819274",
    "long": "28.332451"
},
"clients": "525"
}, {
"num": "61",
"name": ["Ростовская область", "Ростовской области"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "47.222078",
    "long": "39.720349"
},
"clients": "5335"
}, {
"num": "62",
"name": ["Рязанская область", "Рязанской области"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "54.629216",
    "long": "39.736375"
},
"clients": "2119"
}, {
"num": "63",
"name": ["Самарская область", "Самарской области"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "53.195538",
    "long": "50.101783"
},
"clients": "7312"
}, {
"num": "64",
"name": ["Саратовская область", "Саратовской области"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "51.533103",
    "long": "46.034158"
},
"clients": "4961"
}, {
"num": "65",
"name": ["Сахалинская область", "Сахалинской области"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "46.959179",
    "long": "142.738023"
},
"clients": "260"
}, {
"num": "66",
"name": ["Свердловская область", "Свердловской области"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "56.838011",
    "long": "60.597465"
},
"clients": "6997"
}, {
"num": "67",
"name": ["Смоленская область", "Смоленской области"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "54.782635",
    "long": "32.045251"
},
"clients": "980"
}, {
"num": "68",
"name": ["Тамбовская область", "Тамбовской области"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "52.721219",
    "long": "41.452274"
},
"clients": "803"
}, {
"num": "69",
"name": ["Тверская область", "Тверской области"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "56.859847",
    "long": "35.911995"
},
"clients": "1316"
}, {
"num": "70",
"name": ["Томская область", "Томской области"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "56.48464",
    "long": "84.947649"
},
"clients": "1432"
}, {
"num": "71",
"name": ["Тульская область", "Тульской области"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "54.193122",
    "long": "37.617348"
},
"clients": "1742"
}, {
"num": "72",
"name": ["Тюменская область", "Тюменской области"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "57.153033",
    "long": "65.534328"
},
"clients": "1803"
}, {
"num": "73",
"name": ["Ульяновская область", "Ульяновской области"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "54.314192",
    "long": "48.403123"
},
"clients": "2314"
}, {
"num": "74",
"name": ["Челябинская область", "Челябинской области"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "55.159897",
    "long": "61.402554"
},
"clients": "5042"
}, {
"num": "75",
"name": ["Забайкальский край", "Забайкальского края"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "52.033635",
    "long": "113.501049"
},
"clients": "584"
}, {
"num": "76",
"name": ["Ярославская область", "Ярославской области"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "57.626559",
    "long": "39.893804"
},
"clients": "1836"
}, {
"num": "77",
"name": ["Москва", "Москвы"],
"popular": "true",
"coord": {
    "lat": "55.753215",
    "long": "37.622504"
},
"clients": "13916"
}, {
"num": "78",
"name": ["Санкт-Петербург", "Санкт-Петербурга"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "59.939095",
    "long": "30.315868"
},
"clients": "7741"
}, {
"num": "79",
"name": ["Еврейская АО", "Еврейского АО"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "48.792947",
    "long": "132.920245"
},
"clients": "85"
}, {
"num": "82",
"name": ["Республика Крым", "Республики Крым"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "44.948237",
    "long": "34.100318"
},
"clients": "130"
}, {
"num": "83",
"name": ["Ненецкий АО", "Ненецкого АО"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "",
    "long": ""
},
"clients": ""
}, {
"num": "86",
"name": ["Ханты-Мансийский АО", "Ханты-Мансийского АО"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "61.00318",
    "long": "69.018902"
},
"clients": "2237"
}, {
"num": "87",
"name": ["Чукотский АО", "Чукотского АО"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "64.735814",
    "long": "177.518904"
},
"clients": "5"
}, {
"num": "89",
"name": ["Ямало-Ненецкий АО", "Ямало-Ненецкого АО"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "66.529844",
    "long": "66.614399"
},
"clients": "688"
}, {
"num": "92",
"name": ["Севастополь", "Севастополя"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "44.616604",
    "long": "33.525369"
},
"clients": "53"
}, {
"num": "95",
"name": ["Чеченская республика", "Чеченской республики"],
"popular": "false",
"coord": {
    "lat": "43.31851",
    "long": "45.694271"
},
"clients": "23"
}]
```

он длинный, полностью копировать его не буду.

нужно посчитать общее число всех клиентов(clients) по стране, и записать в переменную

Comment: `const count = daCities.reduce((acc, x) => acc + Number(x.clients || 0), 0)`

Comment: если же `daCities` содержит *лишние* элементы то тогда можно предварительно [отфильтровать](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter): `daCities.filter(i => /*условие*/).reduce((acc, x) => acc + Number(x.clients || 0), 0)`

Comment: скопировал полностью код, можно по подробней ? я в js полный 0

Comment: и зачем давать ответ в виде кода на стороннем ресурсе?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Готовый код конкретно под Вашу ситауцию:

```html
<script>

    // здесь вставьте весь код, который вы перечислили в вопросе

    var allClients = 0;

    daCities.forEach(function (item, index) {

        if(item.clients) {
            return allClients += parseInt(item.clients);
        }

    });

    console.log('result: ', allClients);

</script>
```